# Multiple subquery criteria or looping in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

Is it possible to perform a "foreach"-like query in a single SQL statement?  My specific implementation is using SQLite, so suggestions with compatible syntax are preferred.

Example: Let's say we have a table similar to the following:

```
simulation_id  |  sprite_id  |  time | x  |  y
1               1             0.0     0.0  0.0
1               2             0.0     5.5  1.6
1               1             1.0     0.1  0.0
1               2             1.0     5.5  1.5
1               3             1.0     9.9  4.1
1               1             2.0     ...
1               2             2.0
1               3             2.0
2               1             0.0
2               1             1.0
2               1             2.0
2               2             2.0
2               1             3.0
2               2             3.0
2               3             3.0
...
```

The key takeaway from the table is that not all "sprite_id" entries may be instantiated at t=0.0.

I would like to retrieve the positions for all sprites at the first instance sprite_id=3 appears *in each simulation*.  So, my ideal query would retrieve the positions for sprites 1, 2, and 3 at t=1.0 for simulation_id=1, and t=3.0 for simulation_id=2.

I believe the query would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT simulation_id, sprite_id, time, x, y 
FROM locations WHERE time = (SELECT MIN(time) FROM locations WHERE sprite_id = 3)
```

...however I would need this run for each simulation_id in the table; is this even possible in a single SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM locations l
WHERE l.sprite_id = 3
AND time = (
  SELECT MIN(time) 
  FROM locations 
  WHERE simulation_id = l.simulation_id AND sprite_id = l.sprite_id
)
```

Or with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT simulation_id, sprite_id, time, x, y
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY simulation_id ORDER BY time) rn 
  FROM locations 
  WHERE sprite_id = 3
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a180435d69da350375b466df2c22357b).
Results:

```
> simulation_id | sprite_id | time   | x    | y   
> ------------: | --------: | ---:   | :--- | :---
>             1 |         3 |    1.0 | .... | ....
>             2 |         3 |    3.0 | .... | ....
```